# Excel formula return values vertically

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, textjoin

I have a formula set up that is collecting all the values to a corresponding Reference cell. My formula is working great and returning all the values its finds for that particular reference  in a single cell (ie 123, 1234, 4422) but I am having trouble trying to figure out how to write it so the value returned are still in a single cell but list vertically instead of horizontally.

this is my code

`=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF('[ISO Priority Tracking Sheet.xlsx]Piping Input'!$A:$A=A2,'[ISO Priority Tracking Sheet.xlsx]Piping Input'!$C:$C,""))`

[image]

Any input helps! I hope to keep my formula pretty similar to what is it now; it took awhile to make it work.

Comment: `=TEXTJOIN(", "&Char(10),...` and make sure that the Wrap Text is enabled for that cell

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked first try :) Ill mark this as answered once the option pops up I think it takes some time

Comment: Only if @ScottCraner posts an answer. Just out of curiosity, what version of Excel are you running.

Comment: @JvdV  excel 2020